# Lifecycle of non-referenced objects as parameters

Tags: java, object, lifecycle

For instance...

```
incomingTemplate = factory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(Utils.getResource(...
```

The StreamSource object is un-referenced ( is there a better term for this? ) hence one cannot call it's close method to ensure that it's resources are cleared up.

Are these Objects any different to normal local variables? Is this affected by whether the object reference ( incomingTemplate) is static?

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
StreamSource ss = new StreamSource(Utils.getResource());
incomingTemplate = factory.newTemplates(ss);
```

Is equal to

```
incomingTemplate = factory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(Utils.getResource()));
```

The only difference is that you do not have direct access to the StreamSource anymore, if you use the second variation.

---

However if incomingTemplate has getStreamSource method, then it really doesnt matter, if you use this :

```
StreamSource ss = new StreamSource(Utils.getResource());
incomingTemplate = factory.newTemplates(ss);
```

or this :

```
incomingTemplate = factory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(Utils.getResource()));
StreamSource ss = incomingTemplate.getStreamSource();
```

Comment: Regarding the lifecycle though is the StreamSource implicitly null as it is unreferenced once used to create the Template object?